# How can I POST to multiple urls at the same time?

Tags: html, expressionengine

Our website is hosted using EE.  I've been tasked to add to our "Contact us" form so that it posts to an external sales lead generation system (hubspot)

We were given an URL to post to, and when I finally found the html for the form in question I noticed that it is already pointing to another sales lead system.  I don't want to remove this URL.  Is it possible to do two posts at the same time?

```
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" 


http://yoursite.yourportal.hubspot.com/?app=leaddirector&FormName=X
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure.  I see some javascript functions in the page.  (I added the new code I want to post too above)

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that with a single request. Use XMLHTTP objects or JQuery.post(); with different URL's and the same data. Simply send multiple requests. Alternatively, you could send one request to your server, where PHP can send it onwards to other pages, as well as other servers, evading the same-origin policy javascript has.

Comment: what max says holds water... to clarify the php side you can use cURL

Answer (score 3):

You could give your form an id and instead of having a btton of type submit, you have a regular button with an id(in this example id is submit) and then using jquery do something  like so on click of the button:

```
$("button#submit").click(function() {
    $.post("https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8", $("form#id").serialize(), function(data){
        //DO something
    });

    $.post("http://yoursite.yourportal.hubspot.com/?app=leaddirector&FormName=X", $('form#id').serialize(), function(data){
        //DO something 
    });
});
```