# How to post query to different controllers in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was wondering if there is any method or ways to post the query to different controllers (or functions) i.e 2 or more from a laravel form. I am using Laravel 5.4 and I want to extract data from multiple tables(3 in my case), then return view to different pages or different pills/tab on a page.

My controller looks like:

```
class QueriesController extends Controller
{
    public function search(Request $search) {
        $data = $search->data;
        $tables = DB::table('tablename1')->where('column', $data)->get();
        return view('/page1', compact('tables'));
    }

    public function query(Request $query) {
        $tdata = $query->data;
        $tables = DB::table('tablename2')->where('column', $tdata)->get();
        return view('/page2', compact('tables'));
    }
}
```

My route looks like:

```
Route::post('/query', 'QueriesController@search');

Route::post('/search', 'QueriesController@query');
```

My form be like:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'search']) !!}
```

Please suggest me some ways. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to handle the posted request with all the set route every single time? Or just one at a time?

Comment: If it works, I can make the necessary changes.

Comment: check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955097/how-can-i-post-to-multiple-urls-at-the-same-time

Comment: Looks like I getting near and near to what I want... Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

Routes:

```
Route::post('/search', 'QueriesController@handleSearch');
```

Controller:

```
class QueriesController extends Controller
{
    public function handlSearch(Request $request) {
        $tabs = [];

        $tabs[] = $this->search($request);
        $tabs[] = $this->query($requst);

        return \View::make('path.to.your.view', [
            'tabs' => $tabs
        ])
    }


    protected function search(Request $search)
    {
        // Your stuff

        return \View::make('path.to.tab.part', [])
    }

    protected function query(Request $query)
    {
        // Your stuff

        return \View::make('path.to.tab.part', [])
    }

}
```

**I think** there is no way to handle a request with more than one route. If you want to do this, you should catch the request with one route. Then in the controller you can call every other handler method.

Comment: Got your point. Using this handler, can i throw table data simultaneously??

Comment: You mean fill a jQuery tabs/pills with the returned view from the handlers?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap tabs/pills. In each tabs/pills I want to catch the return data.

Comment: Sure you can. Store the return data of the controller methods in an array, then in the returned view, display them.

Comment: It's showing errors as "undefined variable"..can u explain me this process a little bit more..??

Comment: Sorry, I could not get to pc for a while. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the idea...Do i need to change something in Controller.php?? It's showing "BadMethodCallException"..

Comment: I need more information to answer. It seems the problem is elsewhere. What method do it not find?

Comment: "BadMethodCallException" ....Method (tablename2) not found in controller.php 
#tablename2 as in my code...

Comment: Sorry, but at this point, I can't help you. Debug the "method not found" problem. It's fully related to your code. The solution for your question is here.